# Storing a password into a variable

Tags: bash, shell, svn

So I am dealing with the command svn co "Url of a repository" and after this command I have a script that I am running to change a file. Now, I want to do this change to multiple repositories, therefore, instead of manually doing the svn co command for each one, I would like to loop through it all. I have all my repo url stored in variables. But whenever I run the svn co command, it requires a username/password. How would i add that to my script so it does not break

Below is a snippet of the for loop i have,,,right now this wont work because svn co requires a password/username to be entered from user.How would i add it to this script?

```
declare -a urls=( url1, url2, url3 )
for i in ${urls[@]}
do 
  svn co $i
  ./second_script
  echo "$i authz complete"
done
```

Comment: If all the repos are on a single server, just arrange for public-key authentication to that server.

Comment: how abouts would you do that? I

Comment: I would [google svn+public-key.](https://www.google.com/search?q=svn%20public-key)

Comment: [Quote your variables](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes?highlight=%28quote%29#When_Should_You_Quote.3F).

Comment: Please see [the documentation](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn-book.html#svn.serverconfig.netmodel.creds).

Answer (score 0):

1. You **must** (AFAICR) clean-up (or change) your WC before every new checkout
2. You can `svn co --username <USER> --password <PASS> ...` and provide these credentials for every repo to your script